# How to pass images saved in drawable folder via CustomAdapter to NewActivity

Tags: java, android, adapter

How can I pass an array of images in `RecyclerView` to `NewActivity.java`? I don't mean images from `row.xml` - I want a set of new images different from `row.xml` to a `NewActivity`. I saved the images in the drawable folder.

My trials below are the relevant classes and activity.

#### File *String.xml*

```html
<string-array name="array_titles">
    <item>"<![CDATA[[01]  general focus]]>"</item>
    <item>"<![CDATA[[02]  general view for delibration]]>"</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="array_lyrics">
    <item>"<![CDATA[general]]>"</item>
    <item>"<![CDATA[ General ]]>"</item>
    <item>"<![CDATA[ General ]]>"</item>
    <item>"<![CDATA[ General ]]>"</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="newbrandDesc">
    <item>"<![CDATA[ description here ]]>"</item>
    <item>"<![CDATA[ description here ]]>"</item>
    <item>"<![CDATA[ description here ]]>"</item>
    <item>"<![CDATA[ here ]]>"</item>
</string-array>
```

#### File *MainActivity.xml*

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewerage"
        android:background="#01312D"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp" />

        <!-- First Row-->

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/viewerage"
        style="@style/scrollbar_shape_style"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

#### File *MainActivity.java*

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String TAG = "MainActivity ----- ; ";
    private static MediaPlayer player;
    String soundfile;
    TextView mDetailTv1;

    RecyclerView mRecyclerview;
    MyAdapter myAdapter;
    int [] MusicFile;
    List<String> title, newDesc, description;
    int[] icon;
    ArrayList<Model> arrayList = new ArrayList<Model>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("Intro Songs");

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        // Listview icons for song titles in position
        icon = new int[]{R.drawable.song, R.drawable.song, R.drawable.song, };

        mRecyclerview = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        mRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        title = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_titles));

        // listview descriptions for songs in position
        description = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_lyrics));

        // listview NewDescriptions (NewActivity) for songs in position
        newDesc = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.newbrandDesc));

        // listview soundfile file for songs in position
        MusicFile = new int[] {R.raw.wex_1, R.raw.wex_2, R.raw.wex_3, , };

        for (int i = 0; i< title.size(); i++) {
            Model model = new Model(title.get(i), description.get(i), newDesc.get(i), icon[i], MusicFile[i]);
            // Bind all strings in an array
            arrayList.add(model);
        }

        // Pass result to listview class
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, arrayList);

        // Bind the adapter to the listview class
        mRecyclerview.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        MainActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                myAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                myAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

                return false;
            }
        });

        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Favorites Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, FavoritesActivity.class));

            return true;

            // Do more funtionality here
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

#### File *MyAdapter.java*

```js
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyHolder> implements Filterable {

    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<Model> models, filterList;  // This array list create a list of array
                                          // which parameter define in our class
    CustomFilter filter;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model> models) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.models = models;
        this.filterList = models;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, null); // This line inflate our row

        return new MyHolder(view); // This will return our view to holder class
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyHolder myHolder, int i) {

        myHolder.mTitle.setText(models.get(i).getTitle()); // Here is position
        myHolder.mDesc.setText(models.get(i).getDesc());
        myHolder.mImageView.setImageResource(models.get(i).getIcon()); // Here we used an image resource

        myHolder.setItemCLickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClickListener(View v, int position) {

                String gTitle = models.get(position).getTitle();
                String gDesc = models.get(position).getDesc();
                BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable)myHolder.mImageView.getDrawable();
                Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();

                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();

                //get our data with intent
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, NewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", models.get(position).getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("brandNewDesc", models.get(position).getBrandNewDesc());
                intent.putExtra("soundfile", models.get(position).getSoundfile());
                intent.putExtra("iImage", bytes);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
                return;
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return models.size();
    }


    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {

        if (filter == null) {
            filter = new CustomFilter(filterList, this);
        }

        return filter;
    }
}
```

#### File *MyHolder.java*

```js
public class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    ImageView mImageView;
    TextView mTitle, mDesc;
    ItemClickListener itemCLickListener;


    MyHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        this.mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mainIcon);
        this.mTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mainTitle);
        this.mDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mainDesc);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        this.itemCLickListener.onItemClickListener(v, getLayoutPosition());
    }


    public void setItemCLickListener(ItemClickListener ic) {

        this.itemCLickListener = ic;
    }
}
```

#### File *CustomFilter.java*

```js
private ArrayList<Model> filterList;

    private MyAdapter adapter;


    public CustomFilter(ArrayList<Model> filterList, MyAdapter adapter) {
        this.filterList = filterList;
        this.adapter = adapter;
    }


    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraints) {

        FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();

        if (constraints != null && constraints.length() > 0) {

            constraints = constraints.toString().toUpperCase();

            ArrayList<Model> filterModels = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < filterList.size(); i++) {
                if (filterList.get(i).getTitle().toUpperCase().contains(constraints)) {
                    filterModels.add(filterList.get(i));
                }
            }

            filterResults.count = filterModels.size();
            filterResults.values = filterModels;
        }
        else {
            filterResults.count = filterList.size();
            filterResults.values = filterList;
        }
        return filterResults;
    }


    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {

        adapter.models = (ArrayList<Model>) filterResults.values;
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

#### File *ItemClickListener.java* - the interface

```js
public interface ItemClickListener {

    void onItemClickListener(View v, int position);
}
```

```js
public class NewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String TAG = "NewActivity ----- ; ";

    // Store instance variables
    private String title;
    private int page;
    TextView mBrandNewDesc;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // Keeps Android screen on while reading through
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        mBrandNewDesc = findViewById(R.id.textView);

        // Get data from previous activity when item of activity is clicked using intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String mActionBarTitle = intent.getStringExtra("actionBarTitle");
        String newDescription = intent.getStringExtra("brandNewDesc");

        // setctionBar Title
        actionBar.setTitle(mActionBarTitle);

        // Get text in text textView
        mBrandNewDesc.setText(Html.fromHtml(newDescription));

        // OK, we are done. Let’s run the project
    }


    @Override
    public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

    }

}
```

Comment: why don't you pass image resource path int value to the activity?

Comment: Please teach me

Comment: If you are starting new activity in your adapter , the new adapter also has another adapter or the same adapter.A;new activity with new adapter-->get your image view in your new adapter and according of your condition change image. If the name of your image is not specified in your new activity, send the name or namepath string by input method and in onResult of new activity do this replacing(Also you can save the image name to a global class parameter (XXX) of new activity and in new adapter extract the image and replace image of imageview with the new image. Get new Img by XXX param)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `drawable>bitmap>byteArray` send the drawable resource id like this code below changed the `onBindViewHolder`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyHolder myHolder, int i) {

    myHolder.mTitle.setText(models.get(i).getTitle()); //here is position
    myHolder.mDesc.setText(models.get(i).getDesc());
    myHolder.mImageView.setImageResource(models.get(i).getIcon()); // here we used imge resource

    myHolder.setItemCLickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClickListener(View v, int position) {

            String gTitle = models.get(position).getTitle();
            String gDesc = models.get(position).getDesc();
            int imageId = models.get(position).getIcon();

            //get our data with the intent
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, NewActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", models.get(position).getTitle());
            intent.putExtra("brandNewDesc", models.get(position).getBrandNewDesc());
            intent.putExtra("soundfile", models.get(position).getSoundfile());
            intent.putExtra("iImage", imageId ); // i pass the int id then you can use this id in your next activity.
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
            return;
        }
    });

}
```

**New Activity**

```
    ImageView imageView;
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent != null && !intent.getExtras().isEmpty()){
        int imageResourceId = intent.getIntExtra("iImage",-1);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageResourceId);
    }
```

Comment: Please sir how do i receive this image in NewActivity?

Comment: Should i recreate fourth parameter(setters and getters) in Model. Also, where do i create array of drawable files in position?

Comment: Is this correct in NewActivity?
byte[] NewIcon = intent.getByteArrayExtra("iImage");

Comment: Confirm!!!. It worked perfectly. Thanks for teaching me the program. God bless you